# Does JQuery get() + array access break the chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a noob at Jquery so forgive me if this is ridiculous, but does get() and [] break the method chain ? I'm attempting to retrieve a single element from a returned Jquery Object :

```
<HTML>

<HEAD><TITLE>A test page</TITLE></HEAD>



<BODY>

<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a second paragraph</p>

</BODY>


</HTML>


<script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var x = $("p").get(1).text();       //This doesn't work       

var y = $($("p").get(1)).text();    //re-wrapping the result does however. 


</script>
```

If this is the case, how do I more succinctly retrieve a designated value, because at the moment the approach I'm using above is a little clunky to say the least.

Comment: `get()/get(index)` as well as `[index]` retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object. See the documentations for more details: http://api.jquery.com/get/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it breaks, `get` converts the jQuery object to a DOM Element object then you cannot use jQuery methods on the selected elements, you can use `eq()` method instead:

```
var x = $("p").eq(1).text();
```

or `:eq()` selector:

```
var x = $("p:eq(1)").text();
```

Note that `get` and `eq` methods are zero-based, `eq(1)` selects the second element.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the other answer in here as well for it's range of possible solutions, but your's gets the nod since it explains why it happens in the first place.

Comment: +1, nice answer. As usual covering all the bases and nice explanation. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var x = $("p:nth-child(1)").text();
```

Or:

```
var x = $("p:first").text();
```

Or even:

```
var x = $("p").eq(0).text();
```

I don't know which one is least "clunky" for you :)